# Change DIVs Bottom-Position and Height to 0, one after each other, smoothly

Tags: jquery, css

I want to set a DIVs position to bottom = 0 and height = 0 after each other, so that the first animation follows the second smoothly, with at the same speed.
The problem is that the DIV adapts it's height to the content, so when I use the same duration for both animations, the speed differs.

Hard to describe it in words for me; here is the link:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#box").click(function () {
        $("#brief").animate({
            bottom: "0px",
        }, 1500, function () {

            $("#brief").animate({
                height: "0px",
            }, 1500, function () {

                $("#open, #openBG").delay(500).hide();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    alert("HEY!");
                }, 800);

            });
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hausmaster/ED4WK/1/#run

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your problem correctly, would the following work for you ?

```
$("#box").click(function () {
    $("#brief").animate({bottom: "0px",}, 1500).animate({height: "0px"}, 1500);
    $("#open, #openBG").delay(3500).fadeOut(0);
});
```

By adding a events sequentially in jQuery, the later starts after the previous event finishes.

On a side note: TweenMax from greenSock should do a nice trick. It is easier to deal with when timed animations are concerned, specially on same and/or different elements. Let me know if you need to know more.

Comment: Thx, if the height of #brief is 1000px in the beginning and I set the duration to 1500, the speed with which the top of the DIV moves is higher than when the height is only 200px because more pixel have to shrink (1500vs200) in the same time (1500ms).But I want that the SPEED not the duration of the animation is always the same,regardless to the DIVs height.I also want the first animation (set bottom to 0) be played with these same SPEED.First #brief's bottom should be set to 0 and then its height to 0, when you just look at the top edge of #brief you see it moving always with the same speed.

Comment: I believe the following should work. You need to get the height of the element and then do a simple math compared to your reference speed.
E.g. Your standard speed for reference is 1500ms for 1000px . Now read the height using  var h = $("#brief").height(); . And do simple Math. h*1500/1000.  This way you will always get the same speed.